# How to do multiple animations smooth and simultaneously?

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm developing a carrom game. I was trying for animating some 20 ImageViews(Coins) together by adding out the animations in a Queue..... The animation of a single View(Coin) is fine but when i'm animating altogether its getting very slow. I want all the coins to animate simultaneously without problem. This is the code which i had written.

```
    private void startAnimations(int ID, float[] values) {
    switch (ID) {
    case 1: // 43 float values




        /*
         * 
         * long timeinmill = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println ("\n++++++++    JAVA  : ANIMATION METHOD ENDING TIME = "+timeinmill+"  +++++++++++\n");
      try {
                  FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("/sdcard/carromjava.txt");
                  BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

                out.write(Long.toString(timeinmill));
                out.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
      }
              //Close the output stream
       */   

        int counter=0;
        int conX=0,conY=1;
        boolean go=false;
        if(watch==0){
            pos=getPositions();
            watch=1;
        }


        long duration = (long) (values[41]*1000); //(values[40] * 1000);
        LinearInterpolator linear_interpolator = new  LinearInterpolator(); //AccelerateInterpolator();
        DecelerateInterpolator linear_interpolator1=new DecelerateInterpolator();
        SetAnimation setAnimation = new SetAnimation();
        setAnimation.duration = duration;
        setAnimation.checkPocketFlag = (int) (values[40]);
        setAnimation.produce_sound_type = (int) (values[42]);
    //  AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
    //  ArrayList<Animator> animationFull=new ArrayList<Animator>();
        //System.out.println("Values length ="+values.length);
    /*  double dx=Math.abs(pos[0]-(values[0]- board_striker/2.0f));
        double dy=Math.abs(pos[1]-(values[1]- board_striker/2.0f));
        double distance=Math.sqrt((double)(dx*dx)+(dy*dy));
        //double velx=dx/values[41];
        //double vely=dy/values[41];
        double duraX= Math.abs((dx/values[43]))*1000;
        double duraY= Math.abs((dy/values[44]))*1000;
        double velocity=Math.sqrt((double)(values[43]*values[43])+(values[44]*values[44]));
        double dura=distance/velocity;*/
        for (int i = -1; i < 19; i++) {
            if (i == -1) {

                //System.out.println("Coins");
                //System.out.println("x="+pos[0]+"Y="+pos[1]);
                //System.out.println("Animx="+(values[0]- board_striker/2.0f)+"Animy="+(values[1]- board_striker/2.0f));

                ObjectAnimator anim1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(striker,
                        "translationX",pos[counter], values[counter++] - board_striker/2.0f );
                ObjectAnimator anim2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(striker,
                        "translationY",pos[counter], values[counter++] - board_striker/2.0f );
                //Setting Interpolator

                anim1.setInterpolator(linear_interpolator);
                anim2.setInterpolator(linear_interpolator);

                anim1.setDuration((long)values[41]);
                anim2.setDuration((long)values[41]);

            //  if((pos[conX] != (values[conX]-board_striker / 2.0f)) && (pos[conY]!=(values[conY]-board_striker / 2.0f))){
                //System.out.println("Animating");
            //  animationFull.add(anim1);
            //  animationFull.add(anim2);
                AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
            //  animatorSet.play(anim1);
            //  animatorSet.play(anim2);

                animatorSet.playTogether(anim1, anim2);
            //  animatorSet.setDuration((long)values[41]);
                animatorSet.setInterpolator(linear_interpolator);
                //animatorSet.start();

                setAnimation.anim_queue.add(animatorSet);
                setAnimation.last_anim = animatorSet;
            //  }
                conX=+2;
                conY=+2;
                continue;
                //break;
            }
            ObjectAnimator anim1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
                    pieces[i].coinImv, "translationX",
                     values[counter++] - board_carrommen/2.0f);//2*i+2
            ObjectAnimator anim2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
                    pieces[i].coinImv, "translationY",
                    values[counter++] - board_carrommen/2.0f);//2*i+2+1

            anim1.setInterpolator(linear_interpolator);
            anim2.setInterpolator(linear_interpolator);

            anim1.setDuration((long)values[41]);
            anim2.setDuration((long)values[41]);

        //  if((pos[conX] != (values[conX]- board_carrommen / 2.0f)) && (pos[conY]!=(values[conY]- board_carrommen / 2.0f))){

        //  animationFull.add(anim1);   
        //  animationFull.add(anim2);   
            AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
            animatorSet.playTogether(anim1, anim2);


            animatorSet.setInterpolator(linear_interpolator);

            //animatorSet.setDuration((long)values[41]);
            setAnimation.last_anim = animatorSet;
            setAnimation.anim_queue.add(animatorSet);
        //  }
            conX+=2;
            conY+=2;
        }   

        if(watch!=0){
            for(int i=0;i<40;i++){
                if(i==0 || i==1)
                    pos[i]=values[i]- board_striker/2.0f;
                else
                    pos[i]=values[i]-board_carrommen / 2.0f;
            }
        }

    /*  animatorSet.playTogether(animationFull);
        animatorSet.setDuration((long) (duration));
        animatorSet.setInterpolator(linear_interpolator);

        setAnimation.last_anim=animatorSet;*/

        // Create a job and push to job queu

        animation_queue_set.add(setAnimation);

        if (read_from_queue) {
            start_set_anim();
            read_from_queue = false;
        }
   }
   }

    anim_listener = new AnimatorListener() {

        long start_time ;

        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //long exit = System.currentTimeMillis();
            //logger.info("\t Duration = "+animation.getDuration()+ ", Animation Start time = "+start_time  +" , +++++++  animation actual end = "+ exit +"\n");
            start_set_anim();
        }

        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // onAnimCancel(animation);
        }
    };

    anim_listener_check_pocket = new AnimatorListener() {

        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // onAnimStart(animation);
            //System.out.println ("\n +++++++  Animation Start delay  =  "+animation.getStartDelay());
            animation.setStartDelay(0);
        }

        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            nativeInterface.IonAnimationEnd();
            start_set_anim();
        }

        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // onAnimCancel(animation);
        }
    };
    private void start_set_anim() {
    if (animation_queue_set.isEmpty()) {
        read_from_queue = true;
        return;
    }
    SetAnimation recent_anim = animation_queue_set.removeFirst();
    Iterator<AnimatorSet> it = recent_anim.anim_queue.listIterator();


    try{

    if (recent_anim.checkPocketFlag != 0) {
        if(recent_anim.last_anim!=null)
            recent_anim.last_anim.addListener(anim_listener_check_pocket);
        else
            start_set_anim();
    } else {
        if(recent_anim.last_anim!=null)
            recent_anim.last_anim.addListener(anim_listener);
        else
            start_set_anim();

}
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception Raised "+e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

/*  recent_anim.last_anim.setStartDelay(0);
    recent_anim.last_anim.start();*/

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        AnimatorSet aset = it.next();
        aset.setStartDelay(0);
        aset.start();
        //(it.next()).setStartDelay(0);
        //(it.next()).start();
        it.remove();
    }
    /*
     * if (animation_queue_set.isEmpty()) { read_from_queue = true; }
     */
}
```

Please help me how to do all the animations Smooth together. I got an idea of going to OpenGL but without going for OpenGL is there any way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using UI classes to animate each object and have many objects that have simultaneous animations, it is always recommended to use low level APIs like OpenGL. Or if you are not happy with learning OpenGL, you can use Cocoas 2D or other good APIs which just create a powerful framework over low level APIs.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable recomenation